# Qt release build requires debug DLLs

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, compiler-construction, qt-creator

I have a rather weird problem deploying my application ... I compile the application in  Release mode, but when I try to run it it requires QtCored4.dll (**notice the letter *d***).

Why doesn't it require the non-debug dll, QtCore4.dll instead?

Comment: There is probably a human error here. If you are sure that you are looking at the correct file (not the debug build) then check with depends.exe to see if it really does require the debug dlls. If so, you should post more details (pro file, build steps, compiler etc.).

Comment: You were right, it was a human error ... I was including a debug 3rd party library build, rather than a release one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was including a debug 3rd party library build, rather than a release one ... Including the latter one fixed the errors.